# Bootstrap mobile menu not showing up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Please see http://paramasivan.in/gisnew/

The mobile menu is not showing up when the browser is resized to 320 px or 480 px.

I believe it is z-index problem but could not figure out why.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove the `<header class="clone">---</header>`from code your menu will work in mobile view also. problem is happening due to code repeatition.

After that you can style menu section with css

Enjoy :)

[image]